# In the place tab of an event, how to change a place without creating a new one?

Tags: civievent, addresses

In an event card, place tab, you can choose to create a new address or use an existing place. with this second option, a drop-down menu allows you to choose an existing address. after a choice, a message warns us that a change in this address may impact the other events that are also related to this address.

In practice, this is not the case: if you change the address (add a department, etc.), a new address is created (the drop-down menu now contains 2 separate addresses) and other related events always keep the old address.

Is this a translation problem in the warning message (we work with the French version) or is it a problem or a bug?

Comment: hmm. i just tried this out on a dmaster (latest unreleased code) at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/manage/location?action=update&reset=1&id=7 and i ended up with just a spinning page.

Comment: Sorry but what is a "spinning page".

Comment: We think it worked before and that it is since the update that the problem arises. Currently Joomla! 3.10.10 and CiviCRM 5.50.1.

Comment: you can go to that link and try yourself. the mouse indicator turns in to a spinning image. it never stopped and hence afaik the data change was not saved

Comment: OK, I had to use demo user. It seems working on this demo website.